# Audio tag in Phonegap app

Tags: cordova, audio

I'm using this code to play audio in my Phonegap app:

```
var audio = document.createElement('audio');
audio.src=mp3; //mp3 is an http/mp3 stream
audio.play();
```

The stream shows on the player, it also seems to start...

[image]
...but it does not make any sound. When testing this in my browser it works perfectly.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The wierded thing just happened. I disconnected the phone from my PC, and that solved this issue. Apple!!